# Prove that $ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} = \mathcal{O}(\log(n)) $.

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, harmonic-numbers

Prove that $ 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n} = \mathcal{O}(\log(n)) $, with induction.

I get the intuition behind this question. Clearly, the given function isn’t even growing at a linear rate, but what is the ‘proper’ proofy way to say that $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \leq \mathcal{O}(\log(n)) $? I was unable to find any useful identities to use for such a summation.

Comment: You can prove by induction $H_{2^n}\le n+1$, where $H_n$ is $n$-th harmonic number.

Comment: We've never gone over what $H$ is in any of my courses? I don't see how they could expect a solution like that.

Comment: $H_n$ is just shorthand for $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I don't follow, if $H_{2^n} \leq n + 1$ how does that help me in bounding the problem when $n + 1 = O(n)> O(log n)$

Edit: Never-mind, I'm an idiot. You're saying $H_{2^n} <= n + 1$ so $H_{log(2^n)} = H_n <= log (n+1) = O(log(n))$

Comment: More interesting is to prove
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \Theta(\log n)$$
or even
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \ln n + \Theta(1)$$

Comment: @Hurkyl: doesn't it follow from integral test?

Comment: On notation: $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$ is technically a *set* of functions. So it is more correct to say that you want to prove that $ 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n} \in \mathcal{O}(\log(n)) $.

Comment: @Code-Guru The `=` in notation `f(n) = O(g(n))`, does not stand for equality.

Comment: @ypercube From what I remember, the author of the textbook for my Algorithms class conciously used $\in$ just to avoid that confusion which I whole-heartedly agree with. Giving common notation a new meaning in a new context can be very difficult on the new students of the topic...

Comment: I agree that it may be confusing but it's used in many Computer Science books.

Comment: @Alex: Yes. And if you take that approach, it takes very little more work to prove the statements I made in addition to the original statement. Given that the extra information is useful (at the very least, knowing it's $\Theta$ instead of $\mathcal{O}$), one should therefore prove it!

Comment: @ypercube, it is confusing, but (unfortunately) the notation is too widespread to change now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm expanding the answer by xan:

Define $H_n=\displaystyle\sum_{1\le k\le n} {1\over k}$, let's prove by induction that $H_{2^n}\le n+1$. This is true for $n=0$ since $H_{2^0}=H_1=1\le 1$.

Now suppose $H_{2^n}\le n+1$. We have:

$$\begin{align}
H_{2^{n+1}} &= \sum_{1\le k\le 2^{n+1}} {1\over k} \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &= \sum_{1\le k\le 2^n} {1\over k} + \sum_{2^n+1\le k\le 2^{n+1}} {1\over k} \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &= H_{2^n} + \sum_{2^n+1\le k\le 2^{n+1}} {1\over k} \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &\le H_{2^n} + \sum_{2^n+1\le k\le 2^{n+1}} {1\over 2^n} \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &\le H_{2^n} + (2^n-1){1\over 2^n} \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &\le H_{2^n} + (1-{1\over 2^n}) \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &\le H_{2^n} + 1 \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &\le (n+1) + 1 \\
H_{2^{n+1}} &\le n+2 \\
\end{align}
$$

Now let's make $m=2^n$, then $n=\lg m$, and:

$$H_{2^n}=H_m\le\lg m+1=\mathcal{O}(\log m)$$

Answer (score 12):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{n}&\leq1+ \int_1^n\dfrac{1}{x}dx\\&=1+\log(x)\Big|_1^n\\&=1+\log(n)-\log(1)\\&=1+\log(n)\\&=\mathcal{O}(\log(n))
\end{align}

Comment: It should be $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le1+\int_1^n\frac1x dx$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a big detail, it's supposed to be a proof by induction.

Answer (score 7):

Using the inequality $1+x\le e^x$, we can derive
$$
\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le\frac1n\le-\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)=\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)\tag{1}
$$
Summing $(1)$ yields
$$
\log(n+1)\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac1k\le1+\log(n)\tag{2}
$$
That is, for all $n\ge1$
$$
\log(n+1)\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k\le1+\log(n)\tag{3}
$$

---

Sums can easily be made into inductions. We will prove $(3)$ by induction using $(1)$.

For $n=1$, $(3)$ holds since $\log(2)\le1\le1$.

Suppose we have $(3)$ for $n-1$:
$$
\log(n)\le\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k\le1+\log(n-1)\tag{4}
$$
Inequality $(1)$ says that
$$
\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\le\frac1n\le\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)\tag{5}
$$
Adding $(4)$ to $(5)$ yields
$$
\log(n+1)\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k\le1+\log(n)\tag{6}
$$
which is $(3)$ for $n$. This finishes the induction.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Think about the integral $\displaystyle\int_1^n \frac{dx}x$.

Comment: Why should he think about it if someone will give him the solution in a minute or two anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \leq \mathcal{O}(\log(n))$.
This means that there is a constant $c > 0$
and an integer $n_0$
such that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \leq c\log(n)$
for all $n \ge n_0$.

Suppose that this is true for some $n$ and $c$.
We want to show that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} \leq c\log(n+1)$
follows.

By the induction hypothesis,
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} + \frac1{n+1}
\leq c \log(n) + \frac1{n+1}
$
.

If we could show that
$c \log(n) + \frac1{n+1} \le c \log(n+1)$,
we would be done.
But $\log(n+1) - \log(n)
= \log(1+1/n) > 1/n
> 1/(n+1)
$,
so this inequality holds
for any $c \ge 1$.

To find a particular $c$ and $n_0$,
look at $n = 3$.
$1 + 1/2 + 1/3 < 2 <
c \log 3$ for $c = 2$.
So $c=2$ will work.

Of course the best value of $c$ is 1,
but that is not needed for a $\mathcal{O}$
result - there just needs to be some $c$.